# Why does Microsoft Edge keep connecting to media-match.com?

Tags: windows, windows-10, browser, chromium, microsoft-edge

**What is happening?**

- According to Process Hacker 2, Microsoft Edge keeps connecting to  `media-match.com`. After doing some research, I found that this website is "a global publication and online networking community". I have never gone to nor been interested in anything related to this, so I am confused to why this is happening.

**When did it start happening?**

- This started happening shortly after I reinstalled Windows 10 on my PC and installed the Chromium version of Microsoft Edge. I am using the latest, 64-bit version of Microsoft Edge, Version 84.0.522.52.

**What extensions do you have installed in the browser?**

- *LastPass*, *TamperMonkey* (with no scripts installed yet), *uBlock Origin*, *Aria2 for Chrome* (Installed from Chrome Web Store), *IBA Opt-Out* (Installed from Chrome Web Store), *IPFS Companion* (Installed from Chrome Web Store), *Tab Manager Plus for Chrome* (Installed from Chrome Web Store) and *Xtreme Download Manager* (XDM, Installed from Chrome Web Store)

Comment: And does that persist with all extensions disabled??

Comment: Backup your current Edge profile.  Delete your Edge profile.  Does the behavior still exhibit itself?  If it does not then your profile is compromised by a potentially malicious add-on.  If it does still exhibit itself then there might be another explanation.

Comment: Interestingly enough, after disabling this plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xtreme-download-manager/dkckaoghoiffdbomfbbodbbgmhjblecj), the requests stopped.